# What is this metal bar in the front of the jigsaw?

Tags: power-tools, jigsaw

Sorry, just one more novice question about my dad's old Bosch PST 50 AE, before I buy new blades, bear with me....

What is this?

[image]

...and is it supposed to be like that and look this way? Or is it broken?

[image]
[image]

...is it not in the way of the blade?

Comment: *"... is it not in the way of the blade?"* The blade is cutting below the foot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That appears to be ref. 52 in the parts diagram, simply identified as "Pin" (part no. 2 603 105 051).

[image: PST 50 AE parts diagram]

But in the manual for a similar vintage model (view [here](https://manuall.co.uk/bosch-pst-50-pe-jigsaw/) on Manuall.co.uk), this is identified as the Contact Guard, possibly a last line of defence in case the user breaks, discards, or chooses not to use the sliding plastic guard.

Thankfully your jigsaw still has the plastic guard and it looks like it is in good condition so you won't have to rely on the pin.

Comment: So i.e. it’s a safety pin for ”your fingers” among other things…

Comment: While the plastic guard is in place and unbroken, it _does_ slide up and down, probably to make changing the blade easier. The "pin" is there in case the user decides (or forgets) to slide the plastic guard back down. I could see that guard _quickly_ getting covered with sawdust, as well, making it near impossible to see where you're cutting, so I can see that it would be intentionally left up at all times. The pin is a backup safety feature.

Comment: @FreeMan certainly on mine (Black&Decker) the guard makes freehand cutting to a line all but impossible.  It's more use working with a fence.  There's a reason it's not sprung to keep it down - use is optional.  But without it you need to use more care to keep your hand away.  Not much more care to be honest - the guide is pretty limited protection

Comment: Graphus, you might consider posting a link to the instruction manual you found. It might save the OP a fair bit of time answering questions he comes up with in the future.

Comment: @FreeMan, I didn't think it was similar enough for that to be worthwhile but I guess there's no harm either, it's hard to tell just how many features they share without the 50 AE's manual to compare it to.

Comment: Extra +1 for the link. (if only...)